# Does a typical OpenGL ES 1.1 game call all gl functions in the background or on the main thread?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, concurrency

I am trying to understand best practices for OpenGL ES 1.1 fixed function pipeline games.

As far as I understand, a context is not thread safe. So you should call OpenGL from only one thread.

When the game runloop has complex calculations, many developers suggest you do them in the background. When it is time to draw, you would then hand the results over to a part of the program that takes the calculated "model" and calls OpenGL functions on the correct thread.

But I hammered it into my mind that OpenGL function calls should also be done in the background for better responsiveness in the user interface. Is this misguided?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using OpenGL ES from a background thread -- you'll just have to design your app a bit more carefully around it. Apple's programming guide has [a chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH409-SW2) about this.

Comment: Using a serial GCD queue it's not that hard to perform OpenGL ES rendering on a background thread, yet guarantee that only one thread will access the OpenGL ES context at one time. I do this all the time, and it can provide significant performance benefits (I've seen up to 40% improvements in rendering performance on multicore devices).

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you Brad. The missing puzzle piece for me is to cancel the background code so no gl function gets called after the app transitions to the background. Can you provide some insight on how you achieve to stop all OpenGL calls while you call OpenGL on a serial GCD queue in the background? I couldn't find a clear recommendation in the guide how to achieve this.

Comment: One way to do this would be to use a boolean flag to pause the addition of new rendering operations, then use a synchronous dispatch from your entering the background delegate methods into your serial queue with a `glFlush()` call within it. This should block until the last OpenGL ES operation has finished, letting your application head safely to the background otherwise.